# Update ttl of all documents

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Document Collection which already have a property named **ttl** and have values which is greater than 0. Now I need to implement the actual **ttl** which is provided by Azure. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure how to answer what's in your question's title, aside from running some type of update operation to update all of the ttl properties.

As far as enabling TTL itself: TTL is enabled in the collection settings:

[image: ttl setting]

You'll need to choose a default ttl for documents without a ttl property (which can be `-1` for a default of "do not expire."

Comment: May be my question is confusing for you. I already have a ttl property which is completely different from Azure's ttl. Now I need to implement the Azure ttl as well. I need to update all the ttls to -1 now at the same time need to enable the ttl as well :)

Comment: @vishnu If you have a property named something other than `ttl`, that won't be seen by DocumentDB as part of its TTL functionality. If your property is named `ttl` (as explained in your question), then enabling TTL will use the existing property. As far as updating your `ttl` values to -1, you need to write an update operation for that. Aside from all that, you're right - I must not understand your question (and I'm pretty sure I still don't). I'd suggest editing the question to explain further (and not putting any more detail here in comments, esp since I might delete this answer).

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck. The `ttl` field is hard-coded. You'll need to migrate your existing `ttl` field to a new field name, maybe `old_ttl` and enable DocumentDB's ttl functionality after that migration is done. No other choice.